# Avoid unused C callback function warning in Cocoa class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, callback, warnings

In my class header file, within the @interface section, I have:

```
static void ReachabilityCallback (SCNetworkReachabilityRef target, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags, void* info);
```

Then in my class .m file, I set this as a callback

```
if (SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback([self reachability], ReachabilityCallback, &context))
    SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop([self reachability], CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
```

And the callback itself is also defined in the .m (within the @implementation)

```
static void ReachabilityCallback (SCNetworkReachabilityRef target, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags, void* info)
{
    BOOL isReachable = ((flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) != 0);
    BOOL connectionRequired = ((flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired) != 0);
    BOOL networkAvailable = (isReachable && !connectionRequired) ? YES : NO;

    // Post a notification to notify the client that the network reachability changed.
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:networkAvailable], kReachabilityKey, nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]  postNotificationName:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

I am getting an unused function warning in my .h file for the static C function. How can I avoid this, since the function is not called by me, but provided to the OS for it to call?

Comment: I changed your tag from C to Objective-C, you'll probably get better answers from that list.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was sufficient... problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `static` keyword indicates that the function is local and private to a specific translation unit (i.e., .M file), so it won't be exported and made available to other .M files. Therefore, you should **not** declare it in your .H file.

My guess is that what's happening is, in any other .M file that includes the .H file, the declaration is *declaring* a local `static` (private) function named `ReachabilityCallback`. However, since the function is *defined* in only one file, the compiler (correctly) gives you a warning about an unused static function declaration for each extra .M file where the header is included.

You should just move the initial declaration to the top of the .M file where it's actually implemented.